# Adding element to a page without manually repositioning previous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Let's say you decide to add a new element to your HTML file. Do you edit the positioning of all the other elements? Is there a better way about this?

For example I had a layout with a couple of div elements and a list. I spent some time making everything look nice on the page. I then decided to add another div element and suddenly everything is out of whack.

Comment: Did you check for responsive design frameworks like `twitter bootstrap`, `materialize` etc?

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Honestly I have no idea what you just said to me. I just started a few weeks ago I am very new to web design. I don't think I am wording my question properly because I haven't had any luck finding advice through google.

Comment: Just don't worry.. It would be good if you be more precise on your problem in SO by adding some code and tell exactly where you need help.. There are certain frameworks like I said before, which helps not only gives you beautiful components to style up your web application/site, but also gives responsiveness reducing your overhead of creating different screens for different devices.. You just query on those frameworks and it explains everything.. Ask for any help if you are stuck but yea be precise.. :)

Comment: Thank you. This was a very general question I'm not sure I have any code I could show that would do the question justice. I will look into bootstrap as someone else suggested as well.

Comment: Yea just go through them, you can resize your browser to see them working.. Also you can try emulators available in the browser to see how you site looks on mobile devices.. :)

Comment: Oh that would be helpful. Any particular emulator you can suggest? I use google chrome

Comment: `Google chorme` itself has lot of emulators.. Just `Right click->Inspect element` or press `F12`, browser console will show up.. There you can see Mobile like icon at tool bar or hit `Ctrl+Shift+M` and you can see different emulators screen size and also change emulators from browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems very open-ended, but nevertheless I just thought to give my two cents.

**Enter: FLEXBOX**

One tool you can use for responsive design (responsive, meaning your page layout  automatically adjusts depending on the screen through which it is being viewed), would be the CSS properties for Flexbox.

I've edited this simple example to show this in action.  This example just uses a few lines of css code for the parent element, but makes the child (box) elements resize and reposition themselves *automatically* based on screen size, without need of any other styling:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
```

view it here: [simple flexbox sample](https://jsfiddle.net/t5ee15y2/369/)

**once you're on that fiddle, resize your browser (or maybe zoom in and zoom out) and look at how the boxes automatically reposition themselves *like magic!*

Interested? Here's something to get you started: [Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is very neat thank you. I looked into bootstrap but I like to learn about how to do things in the native language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the positioning and css of every element added newly in layout. Its very rare that things sit in place. But work will be less if you use responsive css like [bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Oh wow. Is there a more efficient way of doing it? Any tips you can suggest rather than manually changing left: / top: and margins and watching the preview page for changes?

Comment: I will look into Bootstrap. Thank you